# Self concatenate strings on csh

Tags: string, shell, concatenation, csh, argv

I need to concatenate partial content from argv to one of my variable.

I will show you my code:

```
#!/bin/csh

set stringList = ""
foreach param ($argv)
    if($param !~ TEST) then
        set stringList = $stringList " " $param
    endif
end

echo $stringList > /tmp/prova.txt
```

Of course, nothing is printed on the txt file.
Any solution? Thanks.

Comment: turn on the shell debugging/trace feature, change top line to `#!/bin/csh -vx`. You'll probably see where the problem is. Good luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
        set stringList = $stringList " " $param
```

to

```
        set stringList = "$stringList $param"
```